# Unity3D encrypt managed dll VS unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, encryption, dll

I am building an API/plugin in Unity and want to **encrypt my code**.

By my understanding, managed dll (C#) can be decompiled into readable code, while unmanaged dll (C++) is hard to be decompiled into readable code.

But in unmanaged dll, we cannot use Unity class like **MonoBehavior** or **Mesh**.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What do you intend to accomplish by encrypting your code?  If your code is encrypted, it can't be compiled.  If you mean to encrypt your dll, then it can't be used.  What you likely mean is **obfuscate**, which does make things harder, but not impervious.  If you want to protect your code/plugin, use a licence.

Comment: Hi Luke, I don't want other people see and understand my code, if you encrypt as unmanaged dll (c++), you can still use and people cannot see the original code I believe.

Comment: Why don't you want others to see it?  If your dll is encrypted then it can only be used by software that has the decryption key.  I think you are confusing encryption with obfuscation, as I said earlier.

Comment: for example, in Vuforia's API, people cannot see the code in "Plugins/x86/VuforiaWrapper.dll", I dont want people to see it in the same reason as Vuforia, because the algorithm in the code is important.

Answer (score 0):

that is why you should use marshaling.
unity provide a very good, cross platform solution.
call to the c++ dll from the c# code that only holds the client side (no meaningful algorithms)

you can call your c++ dll from your c# environment like this:

`[DllImport (dllName)]`

```
 private static extern void Foo (string s1, string s2, bool ret);
```